# unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport)"

Tags: c++, dll, dllexport, declspec

I'm trying to code a little plugin for bakkesmod because I'm pissing myself off.
I watched the only 2 video that exists on this topic but ... it doesn't work and I have this error for each void - >>  **Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall GameWrapper::HookEvent(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator >,class std::function<void __cdecl(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator >)>)" (_*imp*?HookEvent@GameWrapper@@QAEXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$function@$$A6AXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z@3@@Z) TagName C:\Users\leodu\source\repos\TagName\TagName\TrollTagName.obj    1**

here is my code.

TroolTagName.cpp (not judge the name)

```
#include "TrollTagName.h"

BAKKESMOD_PLUGIN(TroolTagName, "Trool Tag Name", "1.0", PERMISSION_ALL)

void TroolTagName::onLoad() 
{
    this->Log("This is my first Bakkesmod Plugin");

    this->LoadHooks();
}

void TroolTagName::onUnload() 
{

}

void TroolTagName::LoadHooks() 
{
    gameWrapper->HookEvent("Function TAGame.GameEvent_Soccar_TA.EventMatchEnded", std::bind(&TroolTagName::GameEndedEvent, this, std::placeholders::_1));
    gameWrapper->HookEvent("Function TAGame.AchievementManager_TA.HandleMatchEnded", std::bind(&TroolTagName::GameEndedEvent, this, std::placeholders::_1));
}

void TroolTagName::GameEndedEvent(std::string name) 
{
    cvarManager->executeCommand("load_freeplay");
}

void TroolTagName::Log(std::string msg) 
{
    cvarManager->log("TroolTagName: " + msg);
}
```

TroolTagName.h

```
#include "bakkesmod\plugin\bakkesmodplugin.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "pluginsdk.lib")
class TroolTagName : public BakkesMod::Plugin::BakkesModPlugin
{
public:
    virtual void onLoad();
    virtual void onUnload();

    void LoadHooks();
    void GameEndedEvent(std::string name);

private:
    void Log(std::string msg);
};
```

The project and a Dynamic-library dll project.

I tried adding __declspec (dllexport) before void but ... I got this error - >> redefinition; different linkage and I found nothing for this error so I am blocked :(

Comment: ***unresolved external symbol “__declspec(dllimport)”*** Means the code expects you to link to an import library .lib that goes with a dll.

Comment: [pluginsdk.lib](https://github.com/bakkesmodorg/BakkesModSDK/tree/master/lib)